# Shell script to perform column level data validation

Tags: bash, shell

Requirement :

I want to implement one automation scenario for multiple files like i have two file file1.csv and file2.csv.

These files are having different header. I want to create a script which will validate the data like if a column is numeric it should contain numeric value only. If it is date it should contains date only.

And in One parameter file i have stored value like numeric, str, date , numeric file wise. So my motive is to append numeric,str,date,numeric as header and file1.csv and file2.csv .

How can i validate these column wise.

Sample Fil1.csv

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4

100 | XYZ | 200 | 2020-07-11
200 | XYZ | 500 | 2020-07-10
300| XYZ | 700 | 2020-07-09
```

Fil2.csv

```
Col1 , Col2 , Col3 , Col4

XYZ, 100 , 2020-07-11,500
PQR, 200 , 2020-07-12,700
XYZ, 12.32 , 2020-07-10,800
XYZ, 100 , 2020-07-11,500
```

Parameter File:

```
file1_datatype_sequence = numeric |str | numeric | date

file2_parameter_sequence = str,numeric,date,numeric

file_1_delimitor = |

file2_delimiter = ,
```

Temp FIle for File1.csv

```
numeric |str | numeric | date
100 | XYZ | 200 | 2020-07-11
200 | XYZ | 500 | 2020-07-10
300| XYZ | 700 | 2020-07-09
```

Temp FIle for File2.csv

```
str,numeric,date,numeric
XYZ, 100 , 2020-07-11,500
PQR, 200 , 2020-07-12,700
XYZ, 12.32 , 2020-07-10,800
XYZ, 100 , 2020-07-11,500
```

I want to create a generic script to validate data for both files in one script.

temp file for script should be like this

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck in that process? `awk` would be much better than bash or shell.

Answer (score 0):

slow but beginners friendy

copy the above parameters into `param.ini` file to make it work

uncomment the `echo` lines for debugging purposes

Note: `case` *string* does only check for length (because everything can be a string). change the `grep` regex into `[A-Za-z]+` or something if you want to exclude numbers

```
#!/bin/bash

param=param.ini

validate() {

  case "$1" in
    [Dd][Aa][Tt][Ee]*)
      # date
      echo "$2" | grep -oE '^[0-9]{4}.[0-1][0-9].[0-3][0-9]$' && \
      return 0 || return 2
    ;;
    [Nn][Uu][Mm]*)
      # numeric
      echo "$2" | grep -v '\.$' | grep -oE '^[0-9]+\.{0,1}[0-9]*$' && \
      return 0 || return 2
    ;;
    [Ss][Tt][Rr]*)
      # string
      [ ${#2} -ge 1 ] || return 2
      echo "$2"
      return 0
    ;;
    *)
      return 127
    ;;
  esac
}

test -f "$param" || exit 1

# process all files
for file in ./*.csv
  do
    test -f "$file" || continue
    echo "$file" | grep -qi _out.csv$ && continue

    # read file number
    i=$(echo ${file##*/} | grep -oE '[0-9]+' | tail -n1)

    # get delimiter
    d=$(grep -iE "file[^0-9]*$i[^0-9]*delimit" "$param" | head -n1 | cut -d= -f2)
    # get sequence
    s=$(grep -iE "file[^0-9]*$i[^0-9]*seq" "$param" | head -n1 | cut -d= -f2)

    # write header into file_out
    echo "$s" > "${file%.*}_out.csv"

    # delete whitespaces from delimiter string
    d="${d// /}"
    # delete whitespaces from sequence string
    s="${s// /}"

    #echo "i='$i'"
    #echo "d='$d'"
    #echo "s='$s'"

    [ "$i" ] && [ "$d" ] && [ "$s" ] || exit 127

    # read type definition
    col1=$(echo "$s" | cut -d "$d" -f1)
    col2=$(echo "$s" | cut -d "$d" -f2)
    col3=$(echo "$s" | cut -d "$d" -f3)
    col4=$(echo "$s" | cut -d "$d" -f4)

    #echo "col1='$col1'"
    #echo "col2='$col2'"
    #echo "col3='$col3'"
    #echo "col4='$col4'"

    [ "$col1" ] && [ "$col2" ] && [ "$col3" ] && [ "$col4" ] || exit 127

    # process all lines
    while read -r line || [ "$line" ]
      do
        #echo "'$line'"

        # read values
        value1=$(echo "$line" | cut -d "$d" -f1)
        value2=$(echo "$line" | cut -d "$d" -f2)
        value3=$(echo "$line" | cut -d "$d" -f3)
        value4=$(echo "$line" | cut -d "$d" -f4)

        # delete whitespaces from values
        value1="${value1// /}"
        value2="${value2// /}"
        value3="${value3// /}"
        value4="${value4// /}"

        #echo "value1='$value1'"
        #echo "value2='$value2'"
        #echo "value3='$value3'"
        #echo "value4='$value4'"

        # validate data type
        out=$(validate "$col1" "$value1") || continue
        out="$out $d $(validate "$col2" "$value2")" || continue
        out="$out $d $(validate "$col3" "$value3")" || continue
       out="$out $d $(validate "$col4" "$value4")" || continue

        # write valid line_out
        echo "$out" >> "${file%.*}_out.csv"

    done < "$file"
done

exit 0
```

Comment: if you have only one parameter file, how should the script decide which is the correlated csv file? do you want to interpret the words *numeric, str, date* and search for pattern based on the meaning? How especially should be differed between the two *numeric* columns (how should *num_a(=100)* and *num_b(=500)* identified)? or do you planning to hard-code different (fixed) column positions for file1.csv and file2.csv?